# Using pow() in self-defined function yields different result compared to direct use in main()

Tags: c, function, pow

The following C program unexpectedly shows different results when pow() is used in main() and when it is used within a user-defined function:

```
/*****************************************************
 * Compile command:
 *    gcc -Wall -o powhat powhat.c -lm
 *****************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float topowerof3(float f) {
    f = pow(f,3);
    return f;
}

int main() {
    printf("275 to the power of 3:\n");
    printf("topowerof3(): %f\n", topowerof3(275));
    printf("pow()       : %f\n", pow(275,3));
    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
275 to the power of 3:
topowerof3(): 20796876.000000
pow()       : 20796875.000000
```

Any hints why topowerof3() fails?

Comment: `pow()` returns a `double`.  Your `topowerof3()` converts that to `float` for return.  Typical `float` representations provide about 6-7 decimal digits of precision, but your result requires 8.

Comment: To a first approximation, don't use `float`.  If you want a floating-point type, choose `double` unless you know exactly why you should prefer `float` or `long double`.

Comment: Aside - this function can be implemented as `f*f*f` without the need to bring in the whole `math` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float` != `double`

`float` has much lower precision than `double`.

Change function return type and parameter do double and you will get the same results

```
double topowerof3(double f) {
    f = pow(f,3);
    return f;
}

int main() {
    printf("275 to the power of 3:\n");
    printf("topowerof3(): %f\n", topowerof3(275));
    printf("pow()       : %f\n", pow(275,3));
    return 0;
}
```

[image: (C)www.geeksforgeeks.org]
*`scanf` (not `printf`) format specifier

https://godbolt.org/z/WxocvEbv7